# Repeat function to call data from server every second

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, repeat

So if I press the Start button I want to repeat the function "fetchCarData()" every Second till I press the End Button. What's the best way to achieve this, is there any fancy Kotlin way of implementing such a thing?

```
class CarDataSourceImpl(private val carDataService: CarDataService) : CarDataSource {

//Live Data List that can be accessed only by this class
private val _loadedCarData = MutableLiveData<CarResponse>()

//actual Live Data List observed by the Views
override val loadedCarData: LiveData<CarResponse>
    get() = _loadedCarData

//Fetch new Data and notify Observers via Live Data
override suspend fun fetchCarData() {
    try {
        val fetchedCarData = carDataService
            .getData()
            .await()
        _loadedCarData.postValue(fetchedCarData)
    } catch (e: NoConnectivityException) {
        Log.e("Connectivity", "No Connection", e)
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You could use the launch coroutine builder, with fetchCarData in a loop with a check on whether the button has been pressed, with a delay(1000) after every fetchCarData call?

Answer (score 0):

```
var timer=Timer()
    private fun callfunctioneverysecond() {

        val minTask=object : TimerTask() {
            override fun run() {
                //call function here
            }
        }
        timer=Timer()
        timer.schedule(minTask, 0L, 1000 * 1)
        // timer.cancel()//call timer.cancel when click End button
    }
```